# Node js Get Status

Tags: node.js

I get data in node js like this

```
var no_ktp = req.body.cust_noktp
request({
   uri : 'https://evodms-dev.client.com/evoDMM/api/api_customer_all.php?cust_noktp='+no_ktp,
   auth: {
      'bearer': '71D55F995678929'
   },
   rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
   requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
   agent: false,//add when working with https sites

   }, function(error, rows) {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error);
     } else {
       console.log(rows);
     }

 });
```

and the log is like this

[image: console.log(rows)]

but i want to get the status : false, when i try `console.log(rows.body.status)` the log show undefined. how to write it so I get the status?

Thank you for any help...

Comment: can you tell me the output for this `console.log(rows.constructor)`

Comment: what response do you get for `console.log(rows.body)`?

Comment: try this.. `var result = rows.toJSON()` and after this console `rows`. if it doesn't work try `var result = rows.body.toJSON()`

Comment: Your callback function can take a third argument which is the body, see my answer below and the readme : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the status using this way `rows.body.status`if and only if your body is an object !

However, in the log, your object is actually a string, so, you need to first use `JSON.parse(rows.body)` in order to transform your object-string into an actual javascript object. Then you will be able to access any properties using the normal syntax

```
let body = JSON.parse(rows.body);
console.log(body.status) // 'False'
```

**UPDATE**

SO, I just read the readme for the request nodejs package https://www.npmjs.com/package/request
And you can see that the request's callback take actually 3 arguments :

```
(error, response, body)
```

The response arguments si what you called 'rows', so you can, instead of using my method (JSON.parse) you can use instead the third argument provided to the callback function, no need to parse, you can use it directly :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `body` response is not in JSON format but string. You must convert it to JSON by

```
var no_ktp = req.body.cust_noktp
request({
   uri : 'https://evodms-dev.client.com/evoDMM/api/api_customer_all.php?cust_noktp='+no_ktp,
   auth: {
      'bearer': '71D55F995678929'
   },
   rejectUnauthorized: false,//add when working with https sites
   requestCert: false,//add when working with https sites
   agent: false,//add when working with https sites

   }, function(error, rows) {
     if (error) {
       console.log(error);
     } else {
       const body = JSON.parse(rows.body); // parse string to JSON
       console.log(body.status);
     }

 });
```

Comment: Well, JSON is always a string. Your code takes a JSON string and converts it to a javascript object. Converting a string to JSON does not make sense.